# listview extra spacing between items

Tags: android

I have a list view of images and I can't seem to get the extra spacing out from between the vertical items.  Tried lots of things but so far no luck. I can't seem to figure out where the spacing is coming from.

Here's the XML containing the ListView (It's a custom listview that does dragging/sorting)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fan_ban_ctn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fan_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="@string/fan"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ban_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="@string/ban"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ctn_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="@string/ctn"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wireless_mgmt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <com.att.attbusiness.widget.DynamicListView
        android:id="@+id/widget_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/widget_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/wireless_fragment_Container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the list item is here:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wm_plan" />
```

When I programmatically add additional ImageViews within a custom Adaper, I get this
for a result:
[image]

How can I reduce the spacing between the images?

Although I add images to the listview programmatically, I don't do any layout or margins or anything - just images.  I do, however, read my images somewhat differently.  I am loading from a resource id that I build using some String manipulation and assign the bitmaps to ArrayLists.  I have a selected and un-selected version of each, both are same size.

```
private final static String[] widgetNames = new String[] {
    "wm_device", "wm_userinfo", "wm_billing", "wm_plan", "wm_features", "wm_access_options", "wm_applications", 
    "wm_analytics", "wm_manage_a_list"
};

<...>

for (int i = 0; i < widgetNames.length; ++i) {
        int normalID = this.getResources().getIdentifier(widgetNamesOrdered[i], "drawable", "com.att.attbusiness");
        int selectID = this.getResources().getIdentifier(widgetNamesOrdered[i]+"_selected", "drawable", "com.att.attbusiness");
        mWidgetList.add(widgetNamesOrdered[i]);         

        if (normalID != 0) {
            widgetIcons.add(i, (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), normalID));
        }           

        if (selectID != 0) {
            widgetIconsSelected.add(i, (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), selectID));
        }


    }
```

here's the portion of my custom adapter that sets the image in the listview:

```
// if this button isn't the selected, make sure it's off
        if(mSelectedPosition != position){

            holder.widget.setImageBitmap(widgetIcons.get(position));
        }
        else {
            holder.widget.setImageBitmap(widgetIconsSelected.get(position));
            if(mSelectedBtn != null && holder.widget != mSelectedBtn){
                mSelectedBtn = holder.widget;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show creation ImageView and programmatically adding it part of your code.

Comment: added that portion of my getView() in my custom adapter

Comment: have you tried setting your LinearLayouts to layout_height="wrap_content"?, particularly the one containing the ListView

Answer (score 0):

have you tried android:layout_marginTop="0dp" in you xml file?  Otherwise I would just go with a listview instead of linearlayout

Comment: setting margins on the top and bottom to negative works, but it just doesn't seem right to have to do that when I'm simply putting images into a list.

Comment: I understand, but since you are actually building the list in the java file instead of the xml (you have a linear layout), it is the best solution.

Comment: Another possibility is you want your lists to overlap because the content inside them does not take up the whole section

Comment: no, no overlap required or needed. The list is subject to having its elements dragged up or down so they need to be fully visible. The list takes more than the screen size, so the whole space is consumed